# How to set up python function for multiplying multiple variable polynomial

Tags: python, polynomials

I tried to search on here and google to see if I could find the solution but I only come up part of the way there.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23397987/python-polynomial-package-of-multiple-variables) was very helpful, but what I need to do is actually solve the multiplied polynomial, not just visually represent it.

I am struggling with the best way to set this up.  I have also seen the numpy poly1d and polymul, but these seem to have only one variable.  This is what I am trying to do:

```
z1 = w1 * y0 + b1
Square z1 --> so y1 = z1 ** 2 = w1**2 * y0**2 + 2*w1*y0*b1 + b1**2

then I want to multiply out y2 where y2 = (w2 * y1 + b2)**2
```

I can get this simple one to work (it's a neural net with the activation function just squaring the affine function).  But I want to then square this for a 2nd layer, which adds w2 and b2 and y1 into the mix.  On paper it's already very messy.  I would like a way to input one parameter L for layers (above it's 1).

I was trying something like this, storing the exponent and the "block" in a dictionary but it's not really what I am looking for:

```
CW0 = 1
Cb0 = 1

W1_exp = 1
y0_exp = 1
b1_exp = 1

parameters = {}

for l in range(1,L+1):
        #constants
        parameters['CW' + str(l)] = CW0 * CW0
        parameters['CWb' + str(l)] = CW0 * Cb0 + CW0 * Cb0
        parameters['Cb' + str(l)] = Cb0 * Cb0
        
        parameters['CW' + str(l) + '_W' + str(l) + '_exp'] = W1_exp + W1_exp
        parameters['CW' + str(l) + '_y' + str(l-1) + '_exp'] = y0_exp + y0_exp
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you were happy with the answer in the link given at the beginning of your post, I assume you are fine with using `sympy` and you are not going to write code to define a polynomial and do the multiplication, addition etc from the scratch.

You can use `sympy` exactly the same in that post, but I suppose one of the things that you are confused about is how to have numbered variables. Let's say you want to define symbolic variables `x1`, `x2` and `x3` at once. You can use `symbols` command from `sympy` as `x = sympy.symbols( "x1:4" )`. So `x` will be a tuple storing `x1` until `x` with index one less than `4`, i.e. `x3`. Then for each of these variables you just call `x[i]` (i = 1, 2, 3). Now what if the range is varying, in another word you have an integer variable `n` and you want python automatically define symbolic variables `x1`, `x2`, ... until `x` with `n`. Then just use a f-string; `x = sympy.symbols( f"x1:{n+1}" )`.

To expand a symbolic expression such as square of an expression use `expand` command from `sympy`. So here is a piece of code that has a function receiving a nonnegative integer from you and then return the polynomial in the layer that you talked about it in your question.

```
import sympy

def PLayer( n ):
    if type( n ) != int or n < 0:
        raise ValueError( "The input, the layer index, must be a nonnegative integer.")
    y = sympy.Symbol( "y0" )
    w = sympy.symbols( f"w1:{n+1}" )
    b = sympy.symbols( f"b1:{n+1}" )
    output = y
    for i in range( n ):
        output = (w[i] * output + b[i]) ** 2
    return( sympy.expand( output ) )
```

Now let's check it.

```
for i in range(3):
    print( f"The {i}-th layer polynomial is {PLayer( i )},\n" )
```

This is what you will see in your terminal

```
The 0-th layer polynomial is y0.

The 1-th layer polynomial is b1**2 + 2*b1*w1*y0 + w1**2*y0**2.

The 2-th layer polynomial is b1**4*w2**2 + 4*b1**3*w1*w2**2*y0 + 2*b1**2*b2*w2 + 6*b1**2*w1**2*w2**2*y0**2 + 4*b1*b2*w1*w2*y0 + 4*b1*w1**3*w2**2*y0**3 + b2**2 + 2*b2*w1**2*w2*y0**2 + w1**4*w2**2*y0**4.
```